# Apache Cassandra, cqlsh command, issue on windows 10 and python

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlsh

On my computer, I run 3 versions of python, `py2.7`, `py3.8` and `py3.9`, so I changed the *.exe* name to `python27`, `python38` and `python39`. Now I can uninstall `py3.8` but I not `py39` because I need it to work in another project. So, the different versions of python seem to work correctly as evident [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMMfE.jpg).

All different python versions seems to run correctly and also `cassandra -f` command outputs (`nodetool status get ok`).

But now, when I use `cqlsh` command I get following error

```
can't detect python version
```

However, I tried to use the command `python27 cqlsh`, it runs successfully but I got another error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4JSm.jpg) that I have no idea on how to fix.

I hope someone can help me and i apologise for my english, if i made mistakes.

Comment: cqlsh works now only with Python 2. Python 3 will be supported only in Cassandra 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this problem, too. My solution is to carry out the order "python2 -m cqlsh". You need change "python2" to your python2’s name.